# getUserMedia() - selecting rear camera on mobile

Tags: javascript

This is my question.

I'm making a little app that uses JS-OCR to take a photo and detect a word. It works well, but in I only can user the front camera. My idea is to use only the rear camera, it's not necessary to have an option to switch the cameras.

I was reading about the `getUserMedia()` function, but I can't solve the problem. This is the piece of code involved (function `searchForRearCamera()`):

```
function searchForRearCamera() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    //         Check that the browser supports getUserMedia.
    // If it doesn't show an alert, otherwise continue.
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        // Request the camera.
        navigator.getUserMedia(
            // Constraints
            {
                video: true
            },

            // Success Callback
            function (localMediaStream) {

            },

            // Error Callback
            function (err) {
                // Log the error to the console.
                console.log('The following error occurred when trying to use getUserMedia: ' + err);
            }
        );

    } else {
        alert('Sorry, your browser does not support getUserMedia');
    }

    //MediaStreamTrack.getSources seams to be supported only by Chrome

    if (MediaStreamTrack && MediaStreamTrack.getSources) {

        MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function (sources) {
            var rearCameraIds = sources.filter(function (source) {
                return (source.kind === 'video' && source.facing === 'environment');
            }).map(function (source) {
                return source.id;
            });

            if (rearCameraIds.length) {
                deferred.resolve(rearCameraIds[0]);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(null);
            }
        });
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(null);
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

This is [DEMO](https://xaicorporation.com/totemiq2/)

Comment: No need to use a snippet if the snippet cannot run. Just indent code 4 spaces. That said, please read [mcve] and cut down the unnecessary code

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, and thank you for your response. Solved and learned for the next time. ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`navigator.getUserMedia` is long deprecated. Use [navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) now.

To get the rear camera, you can use the [MediaConstraint:video:facingMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Front_and_back_camera) property.
Available values are `'user'` (front camera), and `'environment'` (back camera).

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: false,
  video: {
    facingMode: 'environment'
  }
})
  .then(stream => vid.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(console.error);
```

```html
<video muted autoplay id="vid"></video>
```

Or [as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxbe1zj3/) since null origin StackSnippet's iframe may block the request to gUM.

Comment: To make sure it works, include the 'exact': facingMode: { exact: "environment" }