# Show functionality only for users that have access to environment facing camera

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a functionality that will allow users taking pictures with their mobile device camera. Is there a reliable way to detect if a user has this access? Currently this is a constraint set by:

```
facingMode: { exact: "environment" }
```

I would like to hide this functionality from users that are not able to use device's back camera. Here's the code that works.

```
<script>
    const player = document.getElementById('player');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');

    const constraints = {
        video:
        {
            facingMode: { exact: "environment" }
        }
    };

    captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
        context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    });

    // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then((stream) => {
            player.srcObject = stream;
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting...what happens if the user IS using the back camera but hits the flip icon to switch to the front camera?

Comment: You can't flip it from the web app...

Comment: What happens when you `.catch()` cases where `getUserMedia()` fails, as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52812734/378779)?

Comment: @kmoser I can get error on my laptop: MediaStreamError { name: "OverconstrainedError", message: "Constraints could be not satisfied.", constraint: "facingMode", stack: "" }

Comment: @santa Wouldn't that indicate the rear-facing camera is disabled, which is what you're looking to do?

Comment: I'm not so sure. In the example you provided there's a demo link and in that demo on jsfiddle my laptop was streaming video, which is clearly not an environment facing... But that's a different issue I suppose. So, let's say I decide to hide camera button in my app if a user does not have camera facing environment, do I just .catch(...) after my .then(...) and if error has an error hide/remove the button? How would I check for that specific error? Are you able to put it in the answer, so I can release the bounty, please?

Comment: Lately I worked on similar stuff with React for a Mobile Scanner, I needed to check the back camera to setup frontend to take full sized picture to send it to NodeJS and process it with OpenCV. But when you say "Have the access", you mean if the User has given Android Browser "Camera Permission" or just mean if the User has a builtin camera at the back to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the exact constraint is not met, a `OverconstrainedError` is thrown. You can catch the error and hide an element like so.

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: {
      facingMode: {
        exact: 'environment'
      },
    },
  })
  .then((stream) => video.srcObject = stream)
  .catch((_) => button.style.display = 'none');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/68e5t4z1/13/

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```js
const isMobileDevice = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)

navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
                      || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia)

navigator.getMedia({video: true}, () => {
  if (isMobileDevice) console.log("I'm mobile device with camera")
  console.log("I have camera")
}, () => {
  console.log("I do not have camera")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer  adds an error handling part i.e: `.catch(function(err){` to the `getUserMedia(...)`  method in the OP  i.e: original post.  In the error handling section, all possible errors are detected that would mean the back camera to be unusable and a brief explanation is held as a variable  namely `error_msg`  in the `if..else..` block.

```
    <script>
    const player = document.getElementById('player');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
    
    var constraints = {
     
      video:
            {
                facingMode: { exact: "environment" }
            }
    }
    
    captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
            context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        });
    
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function success(stream) {
    
        
        player.srcObject = stream;
                    
    }).catch(function(err) {
    //log to console first 
    //console.log(err); /* handle the error */
    var error_msg="";
    if (err.name == "NotFoundError" || err.name == "DevicesNotFoundError") {
    
        
          error_msg="Back camera not found error ";
        //required track is missing 
    } else if (err.name == "NotReadableError" || err.name == "TrackStartError") {
        //webcam or mic are already in use 
        
        error_msg="cam is already in use ";
    } else if (err.name == "OverconstrainedError" || err.name == "ConstraintNotSatisfiedError") {
        //constraints can not be satisfied by avb. devices 
        
        error_msg="constraints can not be satisfied by avb. devices ";
        
        
    }
    else if (err.name == "NotAllowedError" || err.name == "PermissionDeniedError") {
        //permission denied in browser 
        
        error_msg="permission denied in browser ";
        
        
    } else if (err.name == "TypeError" || err.name == "TypeError") {
        //empty constraints object 
        
        error_msg="empty constraints object ";
    } else {
    
        //other errors 
        
        error_msg="Errors somehow";
    }
  captureButton.style.display = 'none';
  
  alert(error_msg);
    
});
    </script>
```

You can find a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsf_user/otpuw2x3/11).

In the fiddle the `player`, `canvas` and `context` variables have been omitted as no HTML elements exist with the `ID`s of the variables. I hope you have the HTML elements with the `ID`s in your actual production code. Besides a button with the ID `capture` has been added. These changes were necessary to run the code in the fiddle without producing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain a new 'catch' error handler like above answers and hide that button inside it.

If you still need to switch to the available camera device, you can consider to use navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices method which returns a promise that receives an array of MediaDeviceInfo objects.