# navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() returns non-sensical labels and getUserMedia() seems to always be using the same device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, navigator, samsung-galaxy, mediadevices

I have a Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra and I'm trying to use `navigator.mediaDevices` to (1) list all the cameras and (2) show output from any of the cameras.

Here are the device labels when I list all the cameras on my device:

- camera2 1, facing front
- camera2 3, facing front
- camera2 2, facing back
- camera2 0, facing back

As I understand it the phone has 5x total cameras:

- a 108MP wide camera
- a 12MP ultrawide camera
- a 10MP telephoto
- a 10MP periscope telephoto
- front camera.

So 4x of the cameras are rear facing and 1x is front facing. So why is it that `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` returns something else completely different?

My next question is...  when I use *any* of the deviceIds that `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` returned I get the front facing camera view on my phone, even if I select a deviceId whose label is "facing back". What's up with that?

Here's my code:

```
<script>
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});

var getCameraSelection = async () => {
  var devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  var videoDevices = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');
  const options = videoDevices.map(videoDevice => {
    return `<li><a href="#" onclick="useCamera('${videoDevice.deviceId}')">${videoDevice.label}</a></li>`;
  });
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = '<ul>' + options.join('') + '</ul>';
};

getCameraSelection();

var useCamera = async (deviceId) => {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    deviceId: deviceId,
    video: true
  });
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();
  return false;
};
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
<video autoplay></video>
```

Comment: Did you try [other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52812734/4209136)?

Comment: @bigless - that did the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and it took me forever to figure out how to select a specific camera by device id. Unfortunately there are a lot of examples floating around out there that look very similar to yours that do not work as advertised. (Always check the language reference! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

The issue is the `constraints` object you are providing to the `getUserMedia()` method. By providing `{ video: true }`, the video stream provided to the browser uses the 'default' camera that the user's device provides.

Instead, define `deviceId` as a property *within* the `video` property, like so:

```
var useCamera = async (deviceId) => {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
      deviceId: deviceId
    }
  });
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();
  return false;
};
```

As you can see, this is similar to the other answer provided. In that example, although it does work, the camera isn't being selected by the deviceId but rather the first camera found by the browser with a constraint of `facingMode: 'environment'`. Depending on the user's device, you might get very different results. Also, it makes the `getCameraSelection()` function in your code rather useless as it totally ignores the deviceId.

PS If you want to apply additional constraints such as zoom or torch (flashlight) it can be done in a similar manner. Just use the `applyConstraints()` method on the stream's video track. (Providing an example because it has an oddly specific syntax that also took me awhile to discover how to make it work).

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: {
    deviceId: deviceId
  }
});

// applying zoom and turning on flashlight
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].applyConstraints([
  {
    zoom: 2 // 2x zoom
    torch: true // flashlight on
  }
]);
```